# How to do CPI between two Anchor programs of two different versions?

Tags: anchor

I am Trying to a CPI to the Orca Whirlpool Program and its anchor version is `0.20.1` and the version I am using in my program is `0.25.0` and when i try to downgrade my version all other anchor packages are yanked.

[image]

Comment: there is PR on the whirlpool repo that upgraded it to 0.24/0.25 just fyi, i tried to import different versions of anchor into the same project and it *can* work but quickly gets hairy

Comment: Its a nightmare to deal with multiple versions due to packages being yanked so how do you work with multiple versions do you import by github ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. use [anchor-gen](https://crates.io/crates/anchor-gen/0.1.2/dependencies) on the program
2. import the resulting crate in your cargo.toml file

This [should](https://twitter.com/simplyianm/status/1550978429281075201) clear up any errors

Comment: The anchor-gen link has some issue

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the function, you can call the CPI with raw account info regardless of anchor version. For example, say you want to call OpenPosition:

```
let cpi_accounts = whirlpool::cpi::accounts::OpenPosition {
    funder: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
    owner: ctx.accounts.user_state.to_account_info(),
    position: ctx.accounts.position.to_account_info(),
    position_mint: ctx.accounts.position_mint.to_account_info(),
    position_token_account: ctx.accounts.position_token_account.to_account_info(),
    whirlpool: ctx.accounts.clp_pool.to_account_info(),
    token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
    system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
    rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
    associated_token_program: ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info(),
};
// TODO this does not work due to the anchor version mismatch
let cpi_ctx = CpiContext{
    accounts: cpi_accounts,
    program: ctx.accounts.clp_program.to_account_info(),
    remaining_accounts: vec![],
    signer_seeds: &[user_state_signer_seeds!(user_state)]
};
let bumps = OpenPositionBumps{
    position_bump: position_bump
};

whirlpool::cpi::open_position(cpi_ctx, bumps, tick_lower_index, tick_upper_index);
```

First we'll need to serialize the ix data:

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
struct OpenPositionCpiArgs {
    bumps: OpenPositionBumps,
    tick_lower_index: u32,
    tick_upper_index: u32,
}

fn open_position_ix_data(
    bumps: OpenPositionBumps,
    tick_lower_index: u32,
    tick_upper_index: u32,
) -> Vec<u8> {
    let hash = get_function_hash("global", "open_position");
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    buf.extend_from_slice(&hash);
    let args = OpenPositionCpiArgs {
        bumps,
        tick_lower_index,
        tick_upper_index,
    };
    args.serialize(&mut buf).unwrap();
    buf
}
```

Where you get the sighash like so:

```
/// The function discrminator is constructed from these 8 bytes. Typically, the namespace is
/// "global" or "state"
pub fn get_function_hash(namespace: &str, name: &str) -> [u8; 8] {
    let preimage = format!("{}:{}", namespace, name);
    let mut sighash = [0u8; 8];
    sighash.copy_from_slice(
        &anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(preimage.as_bytes()).to_bytes()[..8],
    );
    sighash
}
```

Now you can build the ix from AccountMeta and the ix data you have:

```
fn open_position_cpi_instruction(
    ctx: &Context<BuyBond>,
    program_id: Pubkey,
    bumps: OpenPositionBumps,
    tick_lower_index: u32,
    tick_upper_index: u32,
) -> Result<Instruction> {
    let accounts = vec![
        AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.payer.key(), true), // funder
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.user_state.key(), false), // owner
        AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.position.key(), false), // position
        AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.position_mint.key(), true), // position mint
        AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.position_token_account.key(), false), // position token
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.clp_pool.key(), false), // whirlpool
        // token, system, rent, and associated token programs
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.token_program.key(), false),
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.system_program.key(), false),
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.rent.key(), false),
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.key(), false),
    ];

    let instruction = Instruction {
        program_id,
        accounts,
        data: open_position_ix_data(bumps, tick_lower_index, tick_upper_index),
    };
    Ok(instruction)
}
```

And finally, invoke the ix:

```
    let bumps = OpenPositionBumps { position_bump };
    let tick_lower_index: u32 = 5000; // TODO
    let tick_upper_index: u32 = 10000; // TODO

    let instruction: Instruction = open_position_cpi_instruction(
        &ctx,
        ctx.accounts.clp_program.key(),
        bumps,
        tick_lower_index,
        tick_upper_index,
    )?;

    let account_infos = vec![
        ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),                  // funder
        // Note that the Position is owned by the user_state PDA, not the coupon owner!
        ctx.accounts.user_state.to_account_info(),             // owner
        ctx.accounts.position.to_account_info(),               // position
        ctx.accounts.position_mint.to_account_info(),          // position mint
        ctx.accounts.position_token_account.to_account_info(), // position token
        ctx.accounts.clp_pool.to_account_info(),               // whirlpool
        // token, system, rent, and associated token programs
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info(),
    ];

    invoke(&instruction, &account_infos)?;
```

Also keep in mind that if the CPI uses a mutable account, it has to mutable in your context, and likewise if it's a Signer in the CPI. For example, this ix's context has:

```
    /// CHECK: Validated in Whirlpool CPI
    #[account(mut)]
    pub position_token_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
```

because the ATA is mutable (it uses init) in the CPI.

Answer (score -3):

I'd consider just forking the Whirlpool Program and upgrading it yourself.

Comment: I solved this by using the old anchor version from Github but i still feel there should a better solution to this problem instead of forking and upgrading