# Is there a way to use a later version of solana_program with anchor_lang in rust?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust

It seems that it isn't possible to use a later version for solana_program than ~1.10.29 when including anchor_lang as a dependency. Does anyone know how to potentially get around this?

This is the error I get for clarity:

```
failed to select a version for `solana-program`.
    ... required by package `anchor-lang v0.25.0`
versions that meet the requirements `~1.10.29` are: 1.10.29, 1.10.41, 1.10.40, 1.10.39, 1.10.38, 1.10.35, 1.10.34, 1.10.33, 1.10.32, 1.10.31, 1.10.30
```

Comment: This is unfortunately a known issue right now. I was just talking to Armani about it yesterday, and the goal is to have Anchor publish updates more frequently. In the meantime, we have a fork of Anchor with updated Solana deps that you can build with at https://github.com/clockwork-xyz/anchor/tree/0.25.0-solana.1.13.4.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. I seem to have a dependency flow on effect nightmare. I am trying to integrate with other packages such as whirlpools and jupiter. Looks like even if I specify to use the forked anchor you posted above it still isn't compiling. Would I effectively have to fork every other package that has an anchor dependency to instead read from the forked anchor version as well?

Comment: If you have an Anchor IDL for a program, `anchor-gen` should be able to generate a crate with CPI interfaces for it. https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-do-cpi-between-two-anchor-programs-of-two-different-versions/737#737